# @Protocol & Delegate - Delegate method called, but values not being passed to parent form

Tags: xcode, ios5

Landing Page of my application is a UITableView which has list of menu options (menu.h, menu.m). In ViewDidAppear of menu,m, the application checks if user is logged in and does a segue to Modal Login Form (Login.h, Login.m). In modal Login form, On click of Login the delegate method gets executed, but the values are not passed. Would appreciate, if I am missing something

a) Class LoggedInUserDetails

a1) Class LoggedInUserDetails.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface LoggedInUserDetails : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *isSuccessfullyLoggedIn;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *login;

@end
```

a2) LoggedInUserDetails.m

```
#import "LoggedInUserDetails.h"
@implementation LoggedInUserDetails

@synthesize isSuccessfullyLoggedIn;
@synthesize login;

@end
```

b) Login.h & Login.m

b1) Login.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class Login;
@class LoggedInUserDetails;

@protocol LoginDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) login:(Login *)controller GetLoggedInUserDetails:(LoggedInUserDetails *)loggedinuserdetails;
@end

@interface Login : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <LoginDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)actnLogin:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)actnLogout:(id)sender;

@end
```

b2) Login.m

```
#import "Login.h"
#import "menu.h"

@interface Login ()

@end

@implementation Login
@synthesize delegate;


- (IBAction)actnLogin:(id)sender {
    //[self.delegate didReceiveMessage:@"YES"];
    LoggedInUserDetails *loggedinuserdetails = [[LoggedInUserDetails alloc] init];
    loggedinuserdetails.login   = @"MCONNLEY";
    loggedinuserdetails.isSuccessfullyLoggedIn = @"YES";
    // The line below is getting executed while checking in debug mode but
    // doesnot go to menu.m with the result the login form is constantly shown
    [self.delegate login:self GetLoggedInUserDetails:loggedinuserdetails]; 
}
```

c) Menu.h & Menu.m

c1)Menu.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Login.h"
#import "LoggedInUserDetails.h"

@interface menu : UITableViewController <LoginDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *menuList;
@property (nonatomic, strong) LoggedInUserDetails *userDetails;

@end
```

c2)Menu.m

```
#import "menu.h"

@interface menu ()

@end

@implementation menu
@synthesize menuList;
@synthesize userDetails;

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (![userDetails.isSuccessfullyLoggedIn isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegue" sender:self];
    }    

}

- (void) login:(Login *)controller GetLoggedInUserDetails:(LoggedInUserDetails *)loggedinuserdetails {
    userDetails = loggedinuserdetails;
    IstheUserLoggedIn.text = userDetails.isSuccessfullyLoggedIn;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be setting the delegate anywhere. I would expect to see this in prepareForSegue.

Comment: Just added this in menu.m. Still doesnot work. - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LoginSegue"])
 {
  Login *login = [[Login alloc] init];
  login.delegate = self;
 }
    }

Comment: Don't create a new `Login`! Use segue.destinationViewController

Comment: Thanks. Thanks a lot. It worked. How do I accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be setting the delegate anywhere. I would expect to see this in prepareForSegue.

The view controller about to be presented will be available in `segue.destinationViewController`. You can set self as the delegate here.